# Cleaning a Razer Lachesis mouse

Tags: mouse

(I hope this is on topic, the help said that questions regarding gaming related hardware were OK)

I have owned the old style (4kdps) Razer Lachesis mouse for several years but have never worked out how to clean the top surface, it has been survivable for a while now but the top of the mouse has began to become caked in dust. I have tried rubbing it with cloths, cotton swabs and tissue, damp with water, alcohol and even dry, I have tried dusting it and even blowing highly pressurized air over it but cannot find any way that succeeds in cleaning the rubbery top surface. Dust seems to kind of stick to it and become very hard to remove.

I find either that with softer cloths and tissue that instead of picking up dirt, fibres of the cloth of tissue just stick to the surface, this is even worse when damp. Or if I use hard cloths they just scratch the soft rubbery surface but do not actually clean it.

Has anyone had success cleaning this mouse as it is really annoying having my hand covered in dust every time I use my mouse?